# JavaScript - Remove Unit Separator (Unicode: 0x1f) Character From String

Tags: javascript, special-characters

How do you remove Unit Separator (Unicode: 0x1f) from a string using javascript?

I have string that is creating xml however the Unit Separator character is making the XML invalid. Is there a way in JavaScript to strip out such a character?

I have tried this however it does not work:

`input.replace('/\c_/g', '');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
input = input.replace(RegExp(String.fromCharCode(31),"g"),"")
```

Comment: You're missing a `new` and a second argument to `replace`.

Comment: You are correct, although it doesn't look like I need the new, at least on Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can add a character whose unicode code you know in a javascript string literal using `\xXX`.

This should work :

```
input = input.split("\0x1f").join('');
```

Comment: It should be `"\x1f"`, leave the zero